# Jacobi method works with double, fails with float. What is wrong?

Tags: c, double, precision

I coded a little program to solve a system of n equations with the Jacobi (iterational) method. Below is the code:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
int main() {

float *a, *b, *x, *xnew, temp;
int i, j, k, maxiter=10000000, n=4;

a = malloc(n*n*sizeof(*a));
b = malloc(n*sizeof(*b));
x = malloc(n*sizeof(*x));
xnew = malloc(n*sizeof(*xnew));

srand((unsigned) time(NULL));

//  Filling the matrix
for (i=0;i<=n-1;i++) {
    for (j=0;j<=n-1;j++) {
        a[n*i+j] = rand()%60;
    }
    b[i] = rand();
    x[i] = rand();
    xorg[i]=x[i];
}

//  Establishing diagonal dominance
for (i=0;i<=n-1;i++) {
    temp=0;
    for (j=0;j<=n-1;j++) {
        if (j==i) {continue;}
        temp = temp + a[n*i+j];
    }
    a[n*i+i] = temp+1;
}

//  Solve the system. Break when residue is low
for (k=0;k<=maxiter-1;k++) {
    for (i=0;i<=n-1;i++) {
        temp=0;
        for (j=0;j<=n-1;j++) {
            if (j==i) {continue;}
            temp = temp + a[n*i+j]*x[j];
            }
        xnew[i] = (b[i]-temp)/a[n*i+i];
    }
    temp=0;
    for (i=0;i<=n-1;i++) {
        temp = temp + fabs(x[i]-xnew[i]);
        x[i]=xnew[i];
    }
    if (temp<0.0001) {
        break;
    }
}

printf("Iterations = %d\n",k-1);

return 0;
}
```

The break-out-of-the-loop criterion is ridiculously easy. This program should never fail. Yet it apparently does not converge (it uses up all iterations in the loop), UNLESS I change the floats to doubles. Floats have much greater precision than this. What is wrong?
Compiled with CodeBlocks 16.01 under Windows 7, if that even matters.

Comment: What is `xorg`?

Comment: Why `0.0001` in `if (temp < 0.0001)`?  Should not this vary with FP type?

Comment: It's not clear to me how you're judging that the precision of a `float` should be adequate for this calculation (even supposing that you assume IEEE-754 floating point representation and arithmetic, which C does not guarantee to provide).  Certainly the magnitude of `0.0001` is not enough to go by.

Comment: The matrix `a` is of magnitude about 60 and the right-hand side is of magnitude about `RAND_MAX`. Hence, the magnitude of the solution `x` is crudely of magnitude `RAND_MAX/60.`. Try to `printf("%d\n",RAND_MAX);` : it is likely that 0.001 is smaller than 1e-6*RAND_MAX/60., which would explain why the algorithm fails to converge for float. If 0.001 is higher than 1e-12*RAND_MAX/60., it can converge for double.

Comment: The idea of @chux is the right one : the convergence test should be `if(temp<precision*norm1(x)*some_number_related_to_matrix_condition_number)`

Comment: You said, "floats have much greater precision than this", but in my experience they quite often *don't* have enough precision, especially for numerical work, where the cascaded calculation involved in things like reducing systems of equations can very easily pile up the errors very quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the `float` datatype does not have the required precision for the above algorithm, *given the way is was coded*. The algorithm does converge, but the "residue" will never be low enough to exit the loop.

The way I understand this is that due to the way `float` variables are stored internally, you cannot do computation with extremely small (`0.0001`) and extremely large (`RAND_MAX`) numbers and expect reasonable accuracy, as in the above example (`temp` grows to a huge number in the innermost loop).

Consequently, setting `b[i] = rand()%60;` and `x[i] = rand()%60;` will alleviate the problem.

Setting `b[i] = rand()%6;` `x[i] = rand()%6;` and `a[n*i+j] = rand()%6` will allow an even tighter exit-loop condition to be eventually met.

Interestingly, establishing greater diagonal dominance (change `a[n*i+i] = temp+1'` to `a[n*i+i] = temp+10;` will also make the program converge, when it would previously not.

I was not familiar with the ULP conditions described by others, but will invest some time into that

If future readers of this have the time and energy, maybe they should read ["What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic"](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html), even though I have not.

BTW, `xorg` was to store the original `x` vector, for debugging purposes, because I was having a terribly hard time getting CodeBlocks to debug

Thanks to all for contributing.

Answer (score 0):

`if (temp<0.0001) {` is too fine a request given `float` and the values.

Tried a different limit approach by adding the [ULP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place) of the difference of `x[i]` and `xnew[i]`.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdint.h>

static uint32_t ULPf(float x) {
  union {
    float f;
    uint32_t u32;
  } u;
  assert(sizeof(float) == sizeof(uint32_t));
  u.f = x;
  if (u.u32 & 0x80000000) {
    u.u32 ^=  0x80000000;
    return    0x80000000 - u.u32;
  }
  return u.u32 + 0x80000000;
}

static uint32_t ULP_diff(float x, float y) {
  uint32_t ullx = ULPf(x);
  uint32_t ully = ULPf(y);
  if (x > y) return ullx - ully;
  return ully - ullx;
}
```

...

```
  uint64_t sum0 = -1;
  unsigned increase = 0;
  for (k = 0; k <= maxiter - 1; k++) {
    ...
    uint64_t sum = 0;
    for (i = 0; i <= n - 1; i++) {
      uint32_t e = ULP_diff(x[i], xnew[i]);
      // printf("%u %e %e %llu\n", i, x[i],  xnew[i], (unsigned long long) e);
      sum += e;
      x[i] = xnew[i];
    }
    if (sum < sum0) {
      // answer is converging
      sum0 = sum;
      increase = 0;
    } else {
      increase++;
      // If failed to find a better answer in `n` iterations and 
      //   code did at least n*N iterations, break.
      if (increase > n && k > n*n) break;
    }
```